# Capture location over ip?

Tags: user-tracking, programming, tracking

I want to ask you is it possible to programm a programm (in python) that can track people over their ip adress.
Or do you know a programm that can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question- **Yes, this is possible**.

Here is an example on identifying the geo-location of an IP in Python:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-time-zone-given-an-ip

Security Stack Exchange isn't the site to ask for software/product recommendations, or how to program. So your question will likely be flagged for review.

If your question was related to the security aspects of such a tracking tool and you had done some research on the topic... then that would be an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: For the record, product recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow too. The linked question should have been closed (and I've voted to close it).